# How can I prevent an external script from overriding my main.js configuration

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm building an application using require.js. For a certain part I need to load a 3rd-Party script that is built using require.js as well (it's all minified and built into a single file using almond.js).

For this I inject the script tag like:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.onload = function(){
    // remote widget script has loaded
    scriptDfd.resolve();
};
script.src = endpoints.widgetScript + '?appKey=' + auth.userAppKey + '&dev=1';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

The script gets injected fine and is working, but from that point on I cannot use the module mapping defined in my own `main.js` anymore.

The error that is thrown when I try to access my modules is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined` which sounds like it's not able to find the module anymore (which is easily accessible before I inject the 3rd party script).

Is there any feasible workaround for this?

Comment: Ask the third party to fix the script :-) What is the script used for? Maybe you can load it in an iframe environment instead of the actual page.

Comment: @Bergi that's what I actually just did (it's actually just a 2 1/2 party-script) and they rebuilt their script using a custom namespace: http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#rename - which made it work in an instant. Going to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as proposed in the comments I contacted the vendor of the external script (that is actually just dogfooding the dogfooding of another in-house product) and they used a custom namespace when running the `r.js` build script as described **[here](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#rename)**.

This creates two seperate require.js's that can be configured differently.